# How can I export results from a Pyomo variable to a Pandas dataframe and excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyomo

I have a few Pyomo variables in a model, some with three indices. For the purpose of explaining, one of my variables is

```
model.E_grid = Var(model.i, model.m, model.p, within = NonNegativeReals)
```

and the three indices are i, m and p. After running the model, I would like to see the final values of E_grid with respect to each i, m and p in an pandas dataframe (which will then allow me to export it to excel).
So for example, something like *[i1, m1, p1, 21.00], [i1, m1, p2, 22.00]*, and so on. I have already seen the "block" method which tries to export all the variables in one go (e.g. https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/pyomo-looping-over-a-variable-method) but it doesn't work for me because some of the variables have just 1 index. 
Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Edit: this is specifically what I have tried

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame()
for v in model.component_objects(model.E_grid, active=True):
    for i, m, p in v:
        results_df.at[i,m,p, v.name] = value(v[i,m,p])

print(results_df)
```

But I get the error *ValueError: Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!*

Comment: How would you like the final result to be output? In other words, do you expect to create separate dataframes for variables of differing indices lengths? Can you share some snippets of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I do intend to create separate dataframes. I have included a snippet of what I tried in the question edit for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `component_objects()` should be a component type (eg. `Var`), not a component (ie `model.E_grid`). You can use `.items()` to iterate over an `IndexedComponent`.

Secondly, the error you're seeing is due to the way of indexing the dataframe and setting the value on the fly. If you're just wanting to build a dataframe from the variable values it may be much simpler to just use dict comprehension and then one of `pandas`' dataframe constructors:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.core import ConcreteModel, Set, NonNegativeReals, Var, value

model = ConcreteModel()
model.i = Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3])
model.m = Set(initialize=[4, 5, 6])
model.p = Set(initialize=[7, 8, 9])

model.E_grid = Var(model.i, model.m, model.p, within=NonNegativeReals, initialize=1)

E_grid_data = {(i, m, p, v.name): value(v) for (i, m, p), v in model.E_grid.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(E_grid_data, orient="index", columns=["variable value"])
print(df)
#                           variable value
# (1, 4, 7, E_grid[1,4,7])               1
# (1, 4, 8, E_grid[1,4,8])               1
# (1, 4, 9, E_grid[1,4,9])               1
# (1, 5, 7, E_grid[1,5,7])               1
# (1, 5, 8, E_grid[1,5,8])               1
# (1, 5, 9, E_grid[1,5,9])               1
```

You can now post-process the dataframe if you want to split out the index into a multiindex.

Comment: Hi again, please can I know if it is possible to split the current single column with the name (1,4,7,E_grid[1,4,4] into separate columns? For example, the first column will have 1, second column will have 4, third column 7, fourth column E_grid[1,4,7].

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819120/7312238) `pandas` answer. What you're trying to do is split a single index column into either a multiindex or unique columns so searching SO for those answers will give you loads of results. Hope that helps!